# How to get output results from step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I have created step functions and invoked them as specified in AWS documentation. For output, I am getting

```
{ 
"executionArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:execution:HelloWorld:MyExecution", "startDate": 1385732956.878 
}
```

But, instead of above response I want my API response

```
{ response: DATA}
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
This is the lambda that triggers the state machine:

```
    import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import {APIGatewayEvent} from 'aws-lambda';

const stepFunctions = new AWS.StepFunctions();

export const handler = (event: APIGatewayEvent) => {
  console.log('event: ' + JSON.stringify(event));
  const stateMachineARN = process.env.MACHINE_ARN;
  const params = {
    stateMachineArn: stateMachineARN,
    input: JSON.stringify(event),
  };
  const request = stepFunctions.startExecution(params);
  request.on('error', err => {
    console.log('aca' + err.message);
  });

  request.send();
};
```

And the output of the state machine:

```
{
  "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST",
  "Payload": {
    "isBase64Encoded": false,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {},
    "body": {
      "endpoint": {
        "url": "xxx",
        "method": "POST",
        "request": "xxx"
      }
    }
  },
```

I need to grab that Payload.

Comment: Can you provide the state machine configuration, with sensitive data redacted?

Comment: How are you getting that output, via which command/function? Are you using a specific SDK?

Comment: I edited the post with more info

Answer (score 2):

The `DescribeExecution` function returns the output of a Step Function.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_DescribeExecution.html

How to invoke this will depend on your SDK of choice (AWS CLI, Boto3, Java SDK, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using express workflow you can invoke it [synchronously](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/synchronous-execution.html) to get the result of execution.

For standard workflows you need to use `DescribeExecution` api from [sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_DescribeExecution.html) or [cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/stepfunctions/describe-execution.html) for which input is `executionArn`.